# Integer constant doesn't equate with regular integer?

Tags: php, constants, equals, equality

Quick question: Why does the below always compare as false, despite both showing 22 when printed? And no, the constant doesn't define the int with quotes.

```
<?php
...
if(count($_POST) != _NUM_TEAM_REG_FORM_FIELDS_)
    $fields = $_POST;
else die(Core::FormatError("Incorrect number of form fields."));

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining the constant?

Comment: Like this: define("_NUM_TEAM_REG_FORM_FIELDS_", 22); Note, this site is automatically omitting the underscore before and after the constant identifier.

Comment: Please add a var_export of both, then you can see whether they're strings or not.  Also I think you made an edit to change `!==` to `!=`?

Comment: That is some other constant. I think you should turn the constant into a `Super::$tatic` to show more commitment to statics here as well, but that is no technical need, it only shows l33tn355.

Comment: @therefromhere I tried var_export() and it just prints the number, 22, for each. Yes, I tried != and then !== assuming it may be a strict comparison issue, but both yielded the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Why does the below always compare as false, despite both showing 22 when printed?`
Beacause you have compared it falsely.  (i.e. You have used != instead of ==)

Try below code instead,

```
if(count($_POST) == _NUM_TEAM_REG_FORM_FIELDS_)
    $fields = $_POST;
else die(Core::FormatError("Incorrect number of form fields."));
```

Note, I have COMPARED them as EQUAL TO.

Comment: Good grief. I just realised. This will teach me to post with a headache and painkillers! How embarrassing. Thanks.

Comment: No prob mate. Just waiting for the few mins. to be up :)